# WS-Security: What is the correct way to include multiple user identities in the SOAP Security header?

Tags: web-services, soap, ws-security

I want to pass username/password of userA and userB in one SOAP message. Therefore I want to pass two **UsernameToken** in one SOAP message.

I am thinking in two options:

Option 1) 
**UsernameToken** elements inside **Security** element:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="sec" xmlns:wsu="ut">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
            <wsse:Username>userA</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="text">passA</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-4">
            <wsse:Username>userB</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="text">passB</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>            
</soapenv:Header>
```

---

Option 2)
A **Security** element for each **UsernameToken**:

```
 <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="sec" xmlns:wsu="ut">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
            <wsse:Username>userA</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="text">passA</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>            
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="sec" xmlns:wsu="ut">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-4">
            <wsse:Username>userB</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="text">passB</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>            
</soapenv:Header>
```

--

What is the most standard option 1) or 2)? or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common case of using several users I might recollect is passing message through several intermediate nodes. In terms of SOAP specification they are named Actors and requires [separate wsse:Security element](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/specs/ws-security/ws-security.htm#ws-security__toc6201551) with different soap:actor attributes. It corresponds to option 2) from your question.

Consider the next example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21455_01/common/tutorials/authn_ws_user.html):

```
<soap:Header>        
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="sample" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
       <wsse:Username>sample</wsse:Username>
       <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
  <wsse:Security soap:actor="oracle" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="oracle" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
      <wsse:Username>oracle</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

This example contains two  blocks. The one with "oracle" attribute is used to authenticate the end-user, another without this attribute is used for authentication on the front-end gateway.

You may consider option 1) from your question if your use case supposes simultaneous authentication of several users that are not SOAP actors.